# Margin of error in case of very small sample size

Tags: machine-learning, binning

Say there are some sectors(**Sector**) and some counterparties(**NumCpty**). Each counterparty belongs to a unique sector. Some counterparties fail on a certain task(**CptyFailed**).
I want to do binning of the subsectors basis their **PercentageFails**(CptyFailed/NumCpty).
For demonstration purposes, I have used a simple criteria

Bin1 => [0,0.2]

Bin2 => (0.2,0.5]

Bin3 => (0.5,1.0]

[image]

Now if you follow such a criteria we can clearly see both sector 4 and sector 6 have same percentage fail value(0.6) and hence the same bin(3).

However looking at the number of sample points, one would be more confident of sector6 than sector4 since sector4 hardly has 5 counterparties. So, it's unfair for sector 6 to be in the same bin as sector 4.

**Q: How does one normalize for such cases and do correct binning?**

**Q: How to account for margin of error when data points are really low?**

**Summary:** Getting 1 out of 1 correct and 100 out of 100 correct are both 100% scores,  however 1 out 1 is statistically insignificant due to low number of total data points, so we can't really consider them the same from statistics point of view.

Comment: What do you want to do with this results? Maybe some other approach would be better, so please ask your real question? ...

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen My end objective is to reduce number of sectors to very limited number of bins based on some good logic. Essentially, this will help me reduce the dimensionality of the dataset unlike one hot encoding.

Comment: I suspect then your example with 6 sectors is only a small part of the real data? It might be helpful if you could tell us the larger context!

Comment: Here's the context: I have almost 60 sectors and I wish to encode them to be able to use it in my machine learning model. I don't want to go with one hot encoding because it leads to high dimensionality. Hence binning them based on some logic seemed to me the way to go. Hope this helps.